# Widgets sometimes don't work after reboot

Tags: android, widget, android-widget

What I do is following:

```
// prepare
mAppWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(applicationContent);
mAppWidgetHost = new LauncherAppWidgetHost(applicationContent, R.string.app_name);

// create widget
int appWidgetId = ...; // the id of the widget, that I have saved
AppWidgetProviderInfo appWidgetInfo = mAppWidgetManager.getAppWidgetInfo(appWidgetId);
AppWidgetHostView hostView = mAppWidgetHost.createView(context, appWidgetId, appWidgetInfo);
hostView.setAppWidget(appWidgetId, appWidgetInfo);

// show view
// now I just display the hostView
```

**Problem**

On *some devices* and for *some widgets* it happens that the widget does stop working after reboot (the widgetView is just an empty view after reboot). Any ideas why this happens? I've asked my users to try the same widget in their home launcher and there the widget continues working after reboot as well...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I finded another way to solve it: in XML of widget I added textview with text "widget is updating" and in Java code programmatically hide this textview. So when you are rebooting device and widget is still not appear, this text on widget is the way out of the situation